# Cloudflare WARP VPN not working with docker on Ubuntu

Tags: docker

I have installed `warp-cli` on ubuntu successfully. Everything works fine except docker. When I run a docker container like `docker run -p 9000:8000 docker/image` the container is not accessible on `localhost:9000`.

Thanks!

Comment: Having the same issue wonder what interface that warp vpn is attached to that is messing up docker.